# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field Photo.id to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am using grails 3.3.6 and hibernate 5.1.3 and having the following domain classes

```
class Member {

List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>()
.....

}

class Photo {
...

}
```

I am getting the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   java.lang.Long field Photo.id to java.util.ArrayList
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
>           at org.springsource.loaded.ReflectionFieldReaderWriter.getValue(ReflectionFieldReaderWriter.java:60)
>           at org.springsource.loaded.ReloadableType.getField(ReloadableType.java:1394)
>           at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrFieldGet(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1914)
>           at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
>           ... 186 common frames omitted

Comment: When does this error happen?  What is the code triggering it?

Comment: This seems to happen when loading the Member entity.